# check if a link redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if there is javascript or jquery code I can use to check if a link would redirect the current page, instead of a it opening a new webpage.

I am using ruby on rails and on my site there are links that redirect and links that open a new webpage. I need js that executes when a user clicks on any of the links, if the link redirects, it should prompt a confirmation message then executes the link to redirect.

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if a link points to another part of the same webpage / a different webpage or are you asking how to tell if a link will open in the same window/tab or a new window/tab?

Comment: If those redirect links are offsite, you can grab the href and check if it begins with http (assuming you're using relative links for your pages)

Comment: There's no way from JavaScript to tell whether the server will respond to a URL with a redirect unless the pages are explicitly coded that way.

Comment: By 'redirect' you apparently don't mean a 30x HTTP response, but rather a non-new-window/tab-opening response.  Is that right?

Comment: Ok, from all, the post it seems like there isn't a way to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only ways I'm aware that a link can open a new page are:

- Downloading an attachment (not inline)
- Running 'window.open' directly or through an event callback

Unfortunately, it can be extremely difficult to reliably determine through javascript inspection if these are going to happen.  This is because you'll need to perform reflection on the event chain to check the javascript code, and you'll need to call the server (via ajax call) to check for a data attachment.

The simplest way to do this is to manually examine your own site and see where these are happening.  Then modify the 'click' event to confirm before proceeding.